# API does not get called in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, api, paypal

I am using WordPress to build my website and I'm using PayPal API for payment through a plugin called Paid Membership Pro (http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/homepage/).

The problem occurs when I fill the form, add credit card number and click on submit to do the payment.

A new blank (white) page comes up with nothing inside of it. Since there is no coding involved I was not able to do any bug fixing. Also could not find any similar issue on stackoverflow.

Could you please share your experience if you have had the same issue or if you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a blank white page that means a PHP error is happening but you don't have error display enabled on your server.

Open your wp-config.php and set WP_DEBUG to true.  If it's not in there [just add it](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG).

Then when you go through that process you should see actual errors displayed on the screen so you can see what's wrong and get it fixed.